# Python regex matching on strings I don't want

Tags: python, regex

This is my first attempt at trying to use regex with Python or at all, and it is not working as expected. I want a regex to match any alphabetic character or underscore as the first character, then any number of alphanumeric characters or underscores after. The regex I am using is '^[a-z_,A-Z][a-z_A-Z0-9]*', which seems to produce what I want at pythex.org, but in my code it is matching strings that I do not want.

My code is as follows:

```
isMatch = re.match('^[a-z_A-Z][a-z_A-Z0-9]*', someString)
return True if isMatch else False
```

Two examples of strings that are matching that I don't want are: "qq-q" and "va[r". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show us what `someString` is

Comment: Well, the first two characters match exactly as expected, with either `[a-z_A-Z]` matching and then `[a-z_A-Z0-9]` matching. The `*` after those two conditions symbolize that the previous statement can be zero or more times repeating. The pattern matches the beginning part of a string as valid, and then ignore the rest because you're missing an ending `$` or any additional pattern to show that you want to end the search there.

Comment: If you're trying to write a function that detects whether a string is a valid Python identifier, you can do that without regex: try the `str.isidentifier()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you just forgot the `$` at the end of your regex to specify the end of the string.

```
isMatch = re.match('^[a-z_A-Z][a-z_A-Z0-9]*$', someString)
```

Without that, it will match the beginning of the string and not the entire string, which explains why it worked on `"qq-q"` (`"qq"` is a match) and `"va[r"` (`"va"` is a match).

Comment: Upwards of python 3.4 you can also use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) instead of adding the `^` and `$` anchors